# Change Part of URL String of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, replace

I am wondering if there is a way to change the last part (name of image) in a URL string using jQuery.

Here is what I have:

```
http://domain.com/m/m62RLwnqkpPuKl13jSxURBg/80.jpg
```

and here us what /i need it to be:

```
http://domain.com/m/m62RLwnqkpPuKl13jSxURBg/140.jpg
```

**Question update:**

I need to target and replace the name of the image only, which is "80" in this case, without using the rest of the URL, as the URL path will be different for each image.

```
<div class="image">
<img alt="" src="http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/m62RLwnqkpPuKl13jSxURBg/80.jpg" itemprop="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var s='http://domain.com/m/m62RLwnqkpPuKl13jSxURBg/80.jpg';

s=s.replace(/(.*)\/.*(\.jpg$)/i, '$1/40$2')

alert(s);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/anL7rrcu/)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out the solution. If looking for the same thing, here it is:

```
$('.image').children().each(function () {
    $(this).html(function (i, html) {
        return $(this).html().replace(/80.jpg/g, '140.jpg');
    });
});
```

credit goes to @Eliseu Monar

Thank you!